# ForeignKey to specific queryset django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to refer to specific object of `Model`? Suppose I have some models like below:

```
# models.py

class VehicleCategoryCode(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Code(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(VehicleCategoryCode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    index = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# pay attention to the Model
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Currently `Vehicle` is not linked to any model.

Now Code model is ForeignKey to `VehicleCategoryCode`, which has two objects. In the VehicleCategoryCode the first object *label* (for convenience sake) will be referenced by Vehicle.label, and the second object *model* (once again for convenience) will be referenced by Vehicle.model. So each field in Vehicle can refer to the same model, but different objects.

So basically I'm wondering if something like the pseudo code below can be achieved anyhow.

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    label = models.ForeignKey(VehicleCategoryCode__name='label', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleCategoryCOde__name='model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
Vehicle(models.Model):
    label = models.ForeignKey(
        Code,
        limit_choices_to={'category__name': 'label'},
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    model = models.ForeignKey(
        Code,
        limit_choices_to={'category__name': 'model'},
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

For `ModelForm`s and in the `ModelAdmin` it will limit the choices, note however that tese are *not* enforced by the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ran into a problem, however, when I dealt with database. Is making a separate Model for each is the only way to work around?

Comment: @harryghgim: normally it will only make one table per model and one table per `ManyToManyField`, that is all. The `limit_choices_to` does not even have anything to do with the database.